# How to get the records from database from a particular date..through procedure. date passes as parameter

Tags: sql-server, date

This is my procedure i am unable to get the records for the particular date..

i have the data on particular date but output is zero.. 
            but when i use >= it gives me data..

> using = @Date as parameter gives zero output..
>
> using >= @Date as parameter gives output

my procedure where do i need to modify to get the data according to dates supplied.

```
Declare @ids varchar(max);    
set @ids = (select ids from USers where UserId = 10)      
  select F.Date as DateOfuser,F.ID , (B.FirstName + ',' + B.LastName) as Name,    
A.Group ,E.companyname,E.company ,D.receivedDate    
from Details as A    
inner join Usersnew as B    
on A.newId = B.newId    
inner join Files as D    
on D.DocId = B.Docid    
Inner join PDetails as C    
on (D.GId = c.GId and D.PId = C.Id and D.IsActive='True' and             
(convert(datetime,D.ReceivedDate, 20) = @Date  ))  -- @parameter @date // no output       
and D.GId in(select ID from fnSplitter(@ids))    
inner join PDetails as E    
on E.PId = C.Id    
inner join Information as F    
on F.PId = E.PId
```

how do i get the records on particular day passed as a parameter..

I have the data but its not returning how do i modify my procedure to get
the data

i need to get output based on dates..i have data received through dates so date passed as parameter..

please help?

any idea to get records on a particular date passed as parameter?

why

> = is not returning  >= is returning

can u please explain?

cant we pass = operand in procedure that equals the date passed?

Comment: Probably a date vs date-time issue. Try wrapping them both in code that strips the time off both e.g. DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, D.ReceivedDate)) and do the same for the date parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Simon said. There is probably problem with comparing date to datetime. When you compare date to datetime, date is casted to datetime, e.g. "2017-07-04" is casted to "2017-07-04 00:00:00.000".
Change line:

```
    on (D.GId = c.GId and D.PId = C.Id and D.IsActive='True' and             
(convert(datetime,D.ReceivedDate, 20) = @Date  ))
```

to:

```
on (D.GId = c.GId and D.PId = C.Id and D.IsActive='True' and
(convert(datetime,D.ReceivedDate, 20) >= @Date) AND (convert(datetime,D.ReceivedDate, 20) < DATEADD(dd,1,@Date)))
```

You can also change it to this:

```
on (D.GId = c.GId and D.PId = C.Id and D.IsActive='True' and             
(cast(D.ReceivedDate as date) = @Date  ))
```